# Can I inject a controller into this Formly selectbox object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I am working with the Angular Formly library to generate forms. This library allows you to build forms with JSON objects. I am working on a dynamic parent-child dropdown:

http://jsbin.com/fiqubibawi/edit?js,output

The `vm.formFields` array contains several objects that describe how the input fields should be built. Every one of these objects contains a `controller` object. This is exactly what it sounds like: an Angular controller. Here's an example object:

```
{
    key: 'sport',
    type: 'select',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Sport',
      options: [],
      valueProp: 'id',
      labelProp: 'name',
    },
    controller: /* @ngInject */ function($scope, DataService) {
      $scope.to.loading = DataService.sports().then(function(response){
        $scope.to.options = response;
        return response;
      });

    }
  }
```

My problem: I generate these objects server side (ASP.NET), and send them to the browser with JSON. This means that I can't add the controller functionality to this object. What I would rather have:

```
{
    key: 'sport',
    type: 'select',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Sport',
      options: [],
      valueProp: 'id',
      labelProp: 'name',
    },
    controller: ['MyCoolController']      
    }
  }
```

Is there any way in Angular, or otherwise some dirty JavaScript hack, to get this code to work? It has be a string, as the JSON spec doesn't allow functions to be send over the wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily you are able to use Angular's dependency injection.

Simply declare a new controller

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, DataService) {
  $scope.to.loading = DataService.sports().then(function(response){
    $scope.to.options = response;
      return response;
  });
});
```

Then you are able to inject using the name `'TestController'` (I've updated your [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yisevilitu/edit?js,output) to reflect this)

```
vm.formFields = [{
  key: 'sport',
  type: 'select',
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'Sport',
    options: [],
    valueProp: 'id',
    labelProp: 'name',
  },
  controller: 'TestController'
}, 
...
];
```

Comment: Thanks, great stuff. It would have been nice if this was mentioned in the documentation on the Formly website.